# My screen keeps changing color to vintage color

Tags: display

At first after opening the laptop it would stay the normal color but after a minute it will start to change.

It changes color like the second color [here](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=hue+color&rlz=1C1CHWA_enPH646PH646&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj27LCl47fKAhXIVZQKHZK3AGgQ_AUIBygB&biw=1366&bih=643#tbm=isch&q=vintage+color&imgrc=c6x1N0V4wrSAVM%3A)

W10 64-bit

Display adapter (Intel(R) HD graphics) already up to date

Comment: Do you have f.lux or similar software installed?

Comment: no, but I use dimscreen to lower down my screen brightness but I'm pretty sure dimscreen is not the reason because I use it to another laptop and that laptop doesn't change color to vintage or any other color, it just lowers the brightness

Comment: What sort of laptop? Sounds like its got a CCFL backlight that's going bad

Comment: https://www.asus.com/ph/Notebooks/X453MA/